# Limitations of react and it can able to work as equal as swift iOS programming?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am planning to make enterprise size application, actually web-site in reactjs and mobile application on react-native. Can react-native is as efficient as swift iOS? And if not what are the limiting factors of react-native are there?

Answer (score 0):

Native code is always going to be the most efficient.  React Native runs on two different threads, the native thread and the javascript thread.  So, it's actually a little bit less efficient.  However, it's very doable to keep React Native at 60 frames per second (anything less that 30 frames per second will be noticeable to the user).  The pro's for React Native are that you can deploy to both platforms along with keeping a lot of your code from the web app.  Which is a huge economic benefit.  Other limitations of React Native are that a lot is still being built for RN.  Navigation only now became more standardized.  For a long time, it was a huge pain.  Some native features haven't been built by the community yet, but a lot have.  So, depending on the app, React Native can be a huge win.  If your app is continually requiring native features and it's a behemoth of an app, then maybe not.  Facebook uses both React Native and native modules together to accomplish their goals.